# How can I stop Hint, a Haskell runtime interpreter library, crashing the GHC interpreter?

Tags: haskell, crash, ghci, hint

How can I stop Hint, a Haskell runtime interpreter library, from crashing the GHC interpreter?
It gives "Bus Error", "Illegal Instruction" or "Segmentation Fault" when I try to load a module using it into the GHC interpreter. This a major problem and not just an annoyance because it also crashes my application when I use hint to load code that itself uses hint. I suspect this is related to the large amount of libraries Hint drags in when linking.

I am using Mac OS 10.6.8, GHC version 7.0.4

Comment: It is probably not due to the *number* of libraries, but a problem in one of them (possibly a conflict with another).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved this problem by explicitly passing the function to all code loaded.

For example, instead of doing

```
module Go where
import Run

go :: IO ()
go = do
  blah blah ....
  runFile etc ...
```

I did

```
module Go where

go :: RunFile -> IO ()
go runFile = do
  blah blah ....
  run runFile etc ...
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit? I'm trying to run this http://hpaste.org/69213 from ghci and getting the same error. How would I go about correcting it?

Comment: @PhilipK you will have to compile the code you have. The reason I was able to solve my problem was that I was basically making my own interpreter using hint, and was therefore able to expose a "runFile" function from it. The "ghci" does not expose such functionality so my work around is not possible. Still, you can compile the code and run it at least.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you can't stop that. The ghc api, used by both ghci and hint, cannot handle some concurrent use cases, mostly those involving loading packages and modules into the current context. There's too much global state in the ghc api.

Comment: I appreciate the info but, I really don't like how you closed off the possibility of any other approach.

Comment: @user990666 You explicitly asked about using hint from in ghci. Until the ghc api is improved, there will always be cases where it stomps on itself. Had you given a more specific example of the kind of structure you want to use, I could have given a more specific answer.